# Issue with views that call context.update(csrf(request))

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I am having an issue with any view that calls `context.update(csrf(request))` to set csrf on pages called via POST. This issue basically is that I can't use any custom context processors or ones like `{% if user.is_authenticated %}`

I am using `RequestContext(request)` on `render_to_response`

Any ideas on to resolve this issue?

```
if not request.POST:
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
searchpilotidform = searchpilotid()
searchcallsignform = searchcallsign()
searchairportform = searchairport()
searchairportpairform = searchairportpair()

searchpilotnameform = searchpilotname()
pilots = cid.objects.filter(realname__icontains=request.POST['name'])
context = {'searchairportpairform': searchairportpairform, 'searchpilotnameform': searchpilotnameform, 'searchpilotidform': searchpilotidform, 'query': request.POST['name'], 'pilots': pilots, 'searchcallsignform': searchcallsignform, 'searchairportform': searchairportform}
context.update(csrf(request))
return render_to_response('pilotnamesearch.html', context, content_type=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: If you're using RequestContext, why do you need to add the csrf token manually? That's done for you by the csrf context processor.

Comment: Because if I don't, the csrf tokens are not created on pages loaded via POST

Comment: Then you can't be using RequestContext right. You use one or the other, not both. Show the *full* code of your view.

Comment: I have added an example of one of the views that can only be loaded via POST to the starting post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong parameter to `render_to_response`. It should be `context_instance=RequestContext(request)`.

Since you weren't really using a RequestContext, none of the context processors would work. Once you replace it, there'll no longer be any need to add the CSRF token manually.

`content_type` is something else entirely - the MIME type of the response. Since it's not expecting a RequestContext instance, it's a bit surprising this does not raise an error.